# How to use windows.h setClipboardContent method in a JNI call?

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface

I am implementing a JNI method which calls setClipboardContent() function in windows.h to set windows clipboard content. The header looks as follow. The formatName is the clipboard format, The data is a byte[] in Java. It is the data you want to put in the clipboard.

I am confused about how call the setClipboardContent() function in the JNI method. Can anyone help?

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_msoffice_MSOfficeClipboard_setClipboardContents(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject, jstring formatName, jbyteArray data)
{
    BOOL fSucces =  OpenClipboard(NULL);
        if (fSucces) {
            EmptyClipboard(); 
            const char *str = pEnv->GetStringUTFChars(formatName, NULL);
            if (str = NULL) return false; /* OutOfMemoryError already thrown */
            UINT format = RegisterClipboardFormat(str);

            pEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(formatName, str);

            // This is where I should call setClipboardContent(format, HANDLE) method. I don't know what to do here.

            CloseClipboard();       
      }

      return fSucces;
```

}

Comment: Where were you planning to get the HANDLE from?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the clipboard format is just a blob of data, you need to allocate a chunk of memory with GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE) and copy the data from your data array.  Some clipboard formats require special behavior (CF_BITMAP requires a HBITMAP, etc).

Comment: The thing is in order to call setClipboardContents function, I need to provide a handle to the data. For now, I am confused to how to create the handle (not a pointer). I am new to winapi.

Comment: HANDLE WINAPI SetClipboardData(
  __in      UINT uFormat,
  __in_opt  HANDLE hMem
);

Comment: GlobalAlloc() gives you the handle to pass to SetClipboardData(); as I said, this only works for formats that are memory blobs.

Comment: Hi @Luke, would you please have a look at the newly pasted code above? The memcpy statement throws an error.

Comment: You should uncomment the GlobalLock() and GlobalUnlock() lines as they are required.  Then memcpy into bytes (which should not be const) instead of dataHandle.